# Issue displaying data using ember/handlebars

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, handlebars.js, frontend

I have a few questions. The first is why can't I display data without putting 'in model' when using the each helper? Also I'm having issues showing products specific to the category I'm in?

View an image of my inspect here:

[image]

Currently when I click on a category, it shows all of my products.

I want to show all of my categories, then list my products associated to the category I clicked ( I need these available at all times). Shouldn't I be able to just do the following?

```
<ul class="off-canvas-list">
  <li><label>Solution Category</label></li>
  {{#each category}}
  <li class="has-submenu">
    <a href="#">{{name}}</a>
    <ul class="left-submenu">
      <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
      {{#each products}}
      <a href="#">{{name}}</a>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Router.js**

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('line-of-one');
  this.route('operating-room');
  this.route('sterile-processing');
  this.route('solution');
  this.route('department');
  this.route('category');
  this.resource('products');
  this.resource('presentations', { path: '/presentations' }, function () {
    // this one is nested and dynamic, we need it to see one user at a time with its id
    this.resource('presentation', { path: '/:presentation_id' }, function () {
      // another nested one for editing the current user
      this.route('edit');
    });
    // and a last one to create users
    this.route('create');
  });

  // this is our 404 error route - see MissingRoute just bellow
  this.route('missing', { path: '/*path' });
});

// this handles wrong routes - you could use it to redirect to a 404 route or like here to redirect to the index page
App.MissingRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  redirect: function () {
    this.transitionTo('index');
  }
});
```

**Application Route**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.findAll('category')
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('product', this.store.find('product'));
  }
})
```

**Products Route**

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () { return this.store.find('product') }
})
```

**Category Model**

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  room: DS.attr('string'),
  subroom: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('product')
});

App.Category.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 0,
    room: "Operating Room",
    subroom: "Operating Room",
    image: "Content/Images/Products/Case-Goods.png",
    name: "Case Goods",
    rendertemplate: "sliderTemplate",
    sort: 10,
    products: [0]
  }
]
```

**Product Model**

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  room: DS.attr('string'),
  subroom: DS.attr('string'),
  image: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category')
});

App.Product.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 0,
    room: "Operating Room",
    subroom: "Operating Room",
    category: "Case Goods",
    image: "Content/Images/Products/Case-Goods.png",
    name: "Case Goods Solutions",
    content: "Innovations to reduce procedural delays and keep everything at your fingertips.",
    bullets: [
        { content: "Instant access to supplies and equipment to help minimize procedural delays" },
        { content: "Protection of your sterile supplies behind closed doors with durable, easy-to-clean surfaces and either stainless steel or tempered glass door fronts" },
        { content: "Select freestanding or recessed consoles to fit your space" }
    ],
    sellsheet: "Content/Sellsheets/casegoods.html",
    rendertemplate: "valuePropTemplate",
    sort: 0
  }
]
```

**My Navigation**

```
<ul class="off-canvas-list">
  <li><label>Solution Category</label></li>
  {{#each category in model}}
  <li class="has-submenu">
    <a href="#">{{category.name}}</a>
    <ul class="left-submenu">
      <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
      {{#each product in model}}
      <a href="#">{{{product.name}}}</a>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I each controller properties with `{{#each foo in controller.bar}} ... {{/each}}` where bar is a property of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to explain why this worked but: I was passing my model data to the ApplicationRoute so I didn't need to specify a model to each through. I understand that if your in a view associated with a route and you just use {{#each}} the context will be the data your passing through? The code below ended up working. If someone good provide an explanation that would be greatly appreciated!

```
<ul class="off-canvas-list">
  <li><label>Solution Category</label></li>
  {{#each}}
  <li class="has-submenu">
    <a href="#">{{name}}</a>
    <ul class="left-submenu">
      <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
      {{#each products}}
      <a href="#">{{{name}}}</a>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: please be aware that this is being phased out. https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/ember-2.0-rfc/active/0000-the-road-to-ember-2-0.md

Comment: Ah thank you for the reference. Getting some more rails flavor!

Answer (score 0):

1.The context of your the handlebars is the controller, if you used the snippet below it would work

```
{{#with model}}
 {{each product}}
   ...
 {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

2. i see you have not implemented a custom route handler for `/products` so by default ember will assume that you are looking for all of the products. which makes sense as the url doesnt have any information about the selected category. you could nest product within category, or you could filter the results on the `/products route` using [Query Paramenters](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/)

Comment: {{#with}} doesn't seem to be working as you said. I thought I was retrieving the model data and putting it in the controller with setupController property?

How would I nest product in category? or is filtering the result better?